# Why is GERTY dirty?

Tags: moon-movie

Everything else about that space station  (except SAM) was always very white and clean with the Base resembling a sanitary clean room, **except GERTY.**

Why is that?

Comment: Good question.  Why hasn't Sam cleaned GERTY if his life depends on its continued good operation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is addressed in [an article](http://www.gavinrothery.com/they-never-went-to-the-moon/2011/8/21/sirs-robot-looks-a-little-clean.html) with prop-maker Bill Pearson. In short, the robot needed to look like it had been **in continual usage for fifteen years** and had **suffered from neglect and misuse by its former users** (something which acts as a clue and/or foreshadowing to the twist at the end of the film).

> *The [photo above](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5641f690e4b07d9ae5c82879/t/56a8db690bfe8ea72cca81c7/1314009026004/1000w/Dirty_Gerty_01.jpg) is how Gerty arrived on the set a day before we
> began shooting in the Sarang facility set. As you can see, he is very
> clean and nice and has no graphics or dirtying down on him at all.*
> ...
> *I was worried that **Gerty needed to look like he'd been around for
> fifteen years and also possibly beaten up and abused a bit through the
> course of living with Sam. I don't mean in a negligent way, just the
> same way a fifteen year-old computer might look if you dug it out of
> the garage and put it in your living room.***
> ...
> *I also put some ripped corners so it looked like this happened as
> routine and it occurred to me that I would probably draw on Gerty if I
> was living in the Sarang base. I'd also ride around on the robot arms
> and make them do bucking bronco type tricks when I got bored.*

As to why GERTY (the prop) was *actually* so dirty, this is also addressed in the same interview. The short answer is that he's covered in coffee grounds and has had glue applied to make it look like he's been covered in (now removed) post-it notes.

> ***So I ran off to grab a cup of coffee granules, added in a bit of
> boiling water to make it all mushy and started rubbing him down and
> putting some stray stickers on him** whilst the first setup was being
> shot out in the greenhouse.*
> ...
> *When I was dirtying Gerty down at extremely high speed, I was trying
> to think about what my computers get like after I've had them for a
> couple of years. **I tend to use post-it notes quite a lot and they
> inevitably end up being stuck all over my computers and monitor. I ran
> off to the production office and wrote down some notes that sounded
> like things Sam might not want to forget (such as servicing the boom
> on Rover 3), and just stuck them on him.** Now it's all finished and up
> there on the screen it's a bit weird for me seeing my writing all over
> him.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Sir's robot looks a little clean...](http://www.gavinrothery.com/they-never-went-to-the-moon/2011/8/21/sirs-robot-looks-a-little-clean.html)</sup></sub>